# Activity used to start app doesn't exist! Make sure it exists

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

When I try using Appium to test my Hello World Android app, I get `Activity used to start app doesn't exist! Make sure it exists`

1. I have an apk with a package in it: `com.company.myapp`
2. The package has an activity in it: `MainActivity`
3. The apk targets Android 4.4, API level 19
4. I have a simulated Android device via `adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/emulator -avd 4.4-KitKat-Nexus-4`
5. In DesiredCapabilities, I've tried the following for `app-activity`:

   1. `"MainActivity"`
   2. `".MainActivity"`
   3. `"com.company.myapp.MainActivity"`
6. Appium's log says `debug: Request received with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"newCommandTimeout":"60","app":"/Users/me/Development/workspace/myapp/bin/myapp.apk","platform":"MAC","browserName":"","app-package":"com.company.myapp","device-ready-timeout":"60","device":"android","launch":"true","compressXml":"true","app-wait-activity":"com.company.myapp.MainActivity","app-activity":"com.company.myapp.MainActivity","version":"4.4"}}`
7. Appium creates a session, starts android appium, finds my connected (simulated) device, says App is not installed, App already signed, finds an apk it wants to keep, can't find any to remove, runs `adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm install -r [apk it found that it wants to keep]`, forwards port `4724`, wakes up device getting `{"value":true,"status":0}`, ensures screen is unlocked ...

And then it executes `adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.company.myapp/com.company.myapp.MainActivity` and gives the error message above.

It also tries with . prepended to activity and gives the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that if the app was installed *prior* to running my test, it didn't complain about the Activity being absent.

And if I launch appium with `appium --full-reset` it uninstalls the existing app and then installs *some* apk and finds the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Check package name in .java or .kt in the respective app is same as in XML package name.

for example :
XML - tools:context="com.example.emptyname.MainActivity"
kt - package com.example.emptyname

Answer (score 0):

```
Does not clear the app data and launch the app from the desire activity      
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Galaxy E7");
                   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
                   capabilities.setCapability("version", "5.1.1");
                 capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
                 capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", false);
               capabilities.setCapability("app", "D:/Builds/RSQuare_Live.apk");
                 capabilities.setCapability("app-wait-activity", "com.rr.consultants.base.SpalshScreenActivity");
```